# MYSQL PHP Only one table value is not displaying on frontend - very weird

Tags: php

Good morning,

I'm trying to figure out why a specific value don't want to display on front end when the second value in the same table displays properly?

```
Table: tk_user

username, varchar(225), utf8_general_ci            - value "Chris Mod"
farm, varchar(225), utf8_general_ci                - value "Yes"
```

Username "Chris Mod" displays properly on front end, Farm "Yes" doesn't. I tried to change almost everything with no success. Additionaly I have switched names of rows (Username to Farm and Farm to Username) and guess what - value from old "Farm" row has showed. (WTF) It looks like there is something with - i guess - privileges on a specific row? What the heck is goin on :(

I'm using this script:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("*****","*****","*****","*****");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tk_user");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Farmer?</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['farm'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Value "Chris Mod" (Username) displays, value "Yes" (Farm) doesn't display.

Structures of "Username" and "Farm" are equal in mysql.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/9wNT1D8

Please help, guys..

Comment: Can you post the code you use to display those values?

Comment: Hi, i've edited post

Comment: But how looks frontend code / query / passing data.

Comment: Could it be that `farm` field is `Farm` (title case) or has a different name, such as `farms`? This would explain why your code cannot display it. You should dump $row using print_r() function to see exactly what's inside.

Comment: Yes I checked it 10x times :( Everything is okay. This is very weird.. It lookes like the code can't see this value (like it was missing). Permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try echo "". $row['username']. ""; add a newline symbol